# How to find curve which I have the tangent vector field to in polar coordinates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am having a fluid-dynamics problem. I am given the flow:

$$u_{\theta}=a, u_{r}=b$$

in polar coordinates.

I am interested in finding a set of curves which have tangets defined by the vector field $\vec{u} = (u_{\theta},u_r)$.

How can I do that?

---

**What I've tried**

I have tried to switch to caartesian coordinates and solve the problem there.

$$u_x=b\cos\phi - a \sin\phi$$
$$u_y=b\sin\phi + a \cos\phi$$

If I have a curve, let's say $\vec{r}(x,y)$, then I express tangentiality by:

$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{ds} \times \vec{u} = 0$$

for arbitrary curve parametrization $s$.

This leads me to:

$$\frac{dr_x}{u_x}=\frac{dr_y}{u_y}$$

($r_x$ and $r_y$ being the $x$ and $y$ components of $\vec{r}$.)

However, I follow through with this method, the expression I end up with is not separable in $x$ and $y$:

$$bydx+axdx=bxdy-aydy$$

So I don't know how to achieve my goal.